# Ubuntu/Apache2 Change PHP Version

Tags: php, ubuntu, pthreads

I'm trying to use pthreads but for this i hafe to install the pthread php extention.

My server is already setup with php 7.0 and as I read whats the best way to use it is i found this https://gist.github.com/emiglobetrotting/4663ffc4484e9384a261#file-php7_zts_pthreads-sh-L95

This is a manual how to compile ur own php version with Thread Safety enabled

i did this and now if I run

```
php -v
```

it show me the correct php version:

```
PHP 7.3.0-dev (cli) (built: May  7 2018 09:54:09) ( ZTS DEBUG )
```

but if i run phpinfo on my Apache I found:

```
PHP Version 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

So now i look for a way to change this in my apache config but what ever i try it leads me to the same problem:

I need a module that i can enable.

So my question is how could i change my apache to the correct version or how can i create/install a module to use the new php version?

Comment: i did many times but the connection between apache and  php7.3.0-dev is still missing

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by following commands.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.3.0-dev ; // To disable a PHP 7.3.0-dev version 
sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; // To enable a PHP 7.0 version
sudo service apache2 restart  // then restart apache
```

Comment: thanks but i need it the otherway: 
disable php7.0 and enable php7.3
but if i try this it sain that there is no module for php7.3.0-dev

Comment: Try with version number with 1 decimal. e.g. php7.3 and omit `0`

Comment: neither php7.3-dev or php7.3, php7, php-dev  not one of  this versions is a module

Comment: ok. then I will need to check what versions are installed on your system. Then I can help more accurately. I am going to delete my answer for now.

Comment: sudo apt list --installed
just show me php7.0 with alle the installed modules

Comment: How to set it to a specific version e.g. 8.0.15